# Cannot display mvc error view when exception occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

While debugging, I cannot display my Error view when an Exception occurs in my controller.

I know I'm missing something here, but cannot figure it out. It never makes it to my ErrorController.

I have a Controller in the Controllers folder called ErrorController.

I can verify the error message in the model variable when it's created.

Here is the exception code in my Controller:

```
filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, "Error", "Index");

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Error",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model)
            };
```

My Error controller simply looks like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ErrorController
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the view name the extension `.cshtml` if C#, or `.vbhtml` if VB.

[Reference](http://dotnetguide.com/2015/01/display-mvc-error-view-when-exception-occurs/).